# Find the sum of all coefficients of the polynom $p(x) = (x ^4 − 3x^3 − x + 1)^9$

Tags: polynomials

A polynomial $$p(x) = (x ^4 − 3x^3 − x + 1)^9$$ is written in standard form. Find the sum of all its coefficients ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any polynomial $p$ the sum of all the coefficients is simply $p(1)$. So the answer is $(1-3-1+1)^{9}=-2^{9}$.

(If $p(x)= \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} a_kx^{k}$ then $p(1)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} a_k$).